# Подбор параметров в линейном уравнении

Tags: математика

Пример:
5x + 8y + 9z +(-2a) = 18.
Задача: найти все неизвестные (x,y,z,a).
Какие на сегодняшний день существуют способы решения данной задачи?
Я должен реализовать данную функцию (псевдокод):

```
var numbers = [5, 8, 9, -2]; // известные в уравнении в примере
var result = 18; // ответ в примере
var arrUnknowns = SelectionParameters(numbers, result); // возвращает массив подобранных параметров
// ответ задачи arrUnknowns = [2, 1, 0, 0]
// надо реализовать функцию SelectionParameters
```

*Мне необходимо написать ф-ю, которая принимает большой массив известных (в примере: 5, 8, 9, -2), принимает конечный результат (в примере: 18) и далее каждое известное множит на неизвестное,суммирует их и возвращает массив найденных "неизвестных".*

---

Почему  мне важно узнать о разных способах решения задачи: в дальнейшем ф-я усложнится, вместе с "известными" (5,8,9,-2) будет приходить их "цена", например ([5, 2], [8, 15], [9, 1], [-2, 26]). Т.к. вариаций подобранных параметров может быть много, то, соответственно нужно вернуть самый "дешевый" вариант, например ответ к задаче (2, 1, 0, 0) будет иметь цену 2*2+15*1+1*0+26*0=19, тогда как можно решить и (1,1,1,2), тут цена будет 2*1+15*1+1*1+26*2=70. Соответственно первый ответ лучше. Если есть идеи как сразу реализовать такую функцию, которая еще и принимает "цену", то обязательно сообщите, спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82128/discussion-on-question-by-aleksandr-sergeevich-----).

Comment: *коммент для себя* в середине книги "Грокаем алгоритмы" есть  алгоритма поиска кратчайшего пути, а на 147 странице есть подсказка как написать ответ